# Can chrome web bluetooth api connect to a Bluetooth V4 device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have read that Web Bluetooth API can connect to Bluetooth BLE devices. I understand that BLE is a part of  Bluetooth V4, but will Web Bluetooth connect to a regular V4 device that is not BLE?

Answer (score 0):

The version number in Bluetooth is mostly irrelevant. More optional features are added in every new version, but that's it. BLE was added in version 4. "Regular V4 devices" does not make sense. If you refer to "Bluetooth Classic" or BR/EDR devices, these are not BLE devices. However you will be able connect to these devices in Web Bluetooth if they run a GATT server, if the OS supports it, since GATT can also run over BR/EDR.